# What does this Prolog list manipulation program do?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to wrap my head around this:

```
r([], _, []).
r([a(H,_)|T], a(H,X), [a(H,X)|T]).
r([a(H,V)|T], a(I,L), [a(H,V)|R]) :-
    H \= I,
    r(T, a(I,L), R).
```

Example:

```
?- r([a(q,1),a(i,4),a(i,5),a(f,4)], a(i,7), L).
[a(q, 1), a(i, 7), a(i, 5), a(f, 4)]
```

Comment: Haise Sasaki, please accept answer on your posts that are not green yet: https://stackoverflow.com/users/14592892/haise-sasaki Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the first `a(H, _)` match in the first argument list with `a(H, X)` you provided as the second argument.

Take your example : the second argument is `a(i, 7)` so the program checks for an element of the first list that can be unified with `a(i, _)`. It finds `a(i, 4)`, which is replaced with `a(i, 7)`.

- First is the sentinel clause.
- Second is the matching clause.
- The third clause just recursively calls itself if it cannot find the match.

Comment: Where do I find the defintion of a sentinel clause? My prolog courses have a bit dust on them and were not held in english, so sentinel just reminds me of a tv show :)

Comment: "Sentinel clause" is new to me too. I think "base case of the inductive definition" (over the list pair (L1,L2) in `r(L1,_,L2)`) is the standard terminology. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction

Comment: It is not an official term, I just used it in the meaning of "end case" or "guard case" that helps terminate the loop. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value .

Comment: I should have just used "base clause" or something. Should I change it?